# Getting nested array elements in multiple documents mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am designing a restaurant menu where i basically have 3 categories.
    I have a condition that my dishes are present at either category but once the dishes added i cannot add more categories further.

```
This is my collection at the last level (3rd categories)

{
    "_id": "34",
    "restaurant_details_id": "R0023",
    "menu": [{
        "catName": "indian",
        "dishList": [],
        "subCatList": [{
            "subCatName": "chinease",
            "dishList": [],
            "subCatList": [{
                "subCatName": "korean",

                "dishList": [{
                    "dishtype": "food",
                    "dishname": "soup"
                }, {
                    "dishtype": "food",
                    "dishname": "soup"
                }],
                "completed": false
            }],
            "completed": false
        }]
    }]
}
```

So if the person enters dishes at first category the collection will be limited to only first level. and there will not be any category further.
So therefore i  have multiple document where retaurant id is common.

Now the question is i have to find the restaurant whose restaurant id="R0023" and dishtype="food". I can find if i have only one document using aggregate() but how it can be when data is present in multiple documents.

I also have to implement it further in my java. I am deeply stuck into it.

Comment: Why did you define "Chinese" as the subcategory of "Indian" and "Korean" as the subcategory of "Chinese"? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It was just a testing, dont take it too serusly. Idea is to get the solution as early as possible @DmytroShevchenko

Comment: To get the solution as early as possible, you should use the simplest data structure possible, because it simplifies working with data. I strongly recommend that you use the approach I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your structure is unnecessarily complicated by nesting. I suggest that you restructure it—introduce a new collection named `dishes` and store dishes like this:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    restaurantId: "R0023",
    category: "indian",
    type: "food",
    name: "Chicken Razala"
}
{
    _id: 2,
    restaurantId: "R0023",
    category: "Chinese",
    type: "food",
    name: "Noodle Soup"
}
```

You'll be able to query documents of this structure very easily.

#### Query

```
db.dishes.find({ restaurantId: "R0023", type: "food" })
```

#### Output

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "restaurantId" : "R0023",
    "category" : "indian",
    "type" : "food",
    "name" : "Chicken Razala"
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "restaurantId" : "R0023",
    "category" : "Chinese",
    "type" : "food",
    "name" : "Noodle Soup"
}
```

Comment: This is the demand of my menu and hierarchy formed in this way. So i am looking for the possible and easiest solution for this structure. Thanks